# Solution Verification: using polar coordinates to solve this limit (as variables approach infinity).

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

> $\lim_{(x,y)\to \infty}\frac{2x+3y}{x^2-xy+y^2}$

Here's what I did: 
$\lim_{r\to \infty} \frac{r(2sin(a)+3cos(a))}{r^2(-sin(a)cos(a))}=\lim_{r\to \infty} \frac{2sin(a)+3cos(a)}{r(-sin(a)cos(a))}=0$

Am I allowed to use polar coordinates when the variables go to infinity? (would appreciate to know why incase it's a yes).

I've never seen it in any example or question before and I'm a little skeptical.

If it's not allowed, I would appreciate a push in the right direction. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This would require $x$ and $y$ to go to $\infty$ along the same ray, which is not what the problem is about.

Comment: @saulspatz Thanks for the comment! could you elaborate a little more? when $(x,y)\to (0,0)$ we also put $r$ and make them converge to zero in the same way. or is it a different story when we're talking about infinity?

Comment: Yes, it's different, because if $r\to0$ then we must be getting close to the point $(0,0)$, but when $r\to\infty$ we're just getting outside of any circle centered at the origin.  If $(x,y)\to\infty$ along the line $x=y$, we may get a different value than if $(xy)\to\infty$ along the line $y=x^2$.

Comment: @saulspatz Thanks this clears it, if it's possible I would love to get a hint on how to approach this

Comment: Actually, I think you're on a good track, if you clean it up a bit.  I'll write an answer

Comment: @saulspatz What do you mean I'm on a good track? I showed only the polar coordinates way and it doesn't work as you explained, I've tried to apply the triangle inequality and more tricks I know but I didn't deal with a limit where variables go to infinity so I get stuck in everyway :)

Comment: I mean you started out okay, but you didn't finish correctly.  I'll explain how to fix it in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea of using polar coordinates is a good one, but you have to be a bit more careful.  Suppose for some positive integer $N$, we have $x>N$ and $y>N$.  Then $(x,y)$ is a point in the first in the first quadrant, so we can write $$x=r\cos\theta\\y=r\sin\theta$$ for some $0<\theta<\frac\pi2$ and some $r>N$.  Now $$\frac{2x+3y}{x^2-xy+y^2}=\frac{2r\cos\theta+3r\sin\theta}{r^2-r^2\sin\theta\cos\theta}=\frac1r\frac{2\cos\theta+3\sin\theta}{1-\cos\theta\sin\theta}$$ (I notice you made a mistake in the denominator.)

Now the problem is that you can't $\theta$ fixed and let $r$ go to $\infty$, because the value of $\theta$ depends on $x$ and and $y$.  If we can show that $f(\theta)=\frac{2\cos\theta+3\sin\theta}{1-\cos\theta\sin\theta}$ is bounded, however, then we can say that the fraction goes to $0$.  This is true because the denominator never vanishes, so that $f$ is a continuous function on a closed interval, and is therefore bounded.

Comment: Thanks alot, so as a lesson to take from my mistake: Every time I use polar coordinates (even if $x,y$ go to zero) I must show the $f(\theta)$ is bounded before finishing my proof?

Comment: It's never enough to show that one factor of a product goes to $0$, because if the other factor goes to $\infty$, you've got an indeterminate form.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another method.  Let $x. y \gt 0.$
$$x^2-xy+y^2=\left(x-{y\over 2}\right)^2+{3\over 4}y^2\ge {3\over 4}y^2 \tag 1$$
By symmetry,
$$x^2-xy+y^2\ge {3\over 8}\left(x^2+y^2\right).$$

The rest is elementary. For example,
$$0\lt \frac{2x}{x^2-xy+y^2}\le {16x\over 3x^2},$$
and the right side goes to zero as $x\to\infty.$

This method will work whenever the denominator is a positive quadratic homogeneous polynomial and the numerator is linear.

(Explaining "symmetry" above: You can get (1) with $x^2$ instead of $y^2$ on the right. Bigger than two numbers implies bigger than their average.)